# path modification does not work

Tags: windows, path

I just installed "sublime text 2" in the folder: "C:\Program Files\Sublime Text 2" where there is the file "sublim.exe"

I tried to modify the path so that I can start "sublime text" by typing in the windows console:

> sublim

So I added the following to the environmental variable PATH:

C:\;C:\Program Files\;C:\Program Files\Sublime Text 2

But when I type

> sublim

I get an error saying that "sublim is not recognized as an internal command".

I did the exact same thing with another computer and it worked perfectly. What can  I do?

Thank you very much for your help

Comment: In reply to the answer, there already is a ".exe" extension

Answer (score 0):

Just go to your C:\Program Files\Sublime Text 2 folder and add the .exe extension to sublim.